# Generate series 0.01 to 0.99

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions

Is there any simple method to get a series:

```
0.01
0.02
0.03
...
...
...
0.97
0.98
0.99
```

like series generation from 1 to 99

```
SELECT *  FROM generate_series(1, 99)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is quite easy:

Use :

```
SELECT a.n
FROM generate_series(0.01, 0.99,0.01) as a(n);
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/80581

```
0.01 - start of series  

0.99 - end of series
```

```
0.01 - increment value from series start to series end
```

Answer (score 3):

Another easy way:

```
select generate_series(1,99)::float/100;
```

The only trickiness here is the need to cast the integer to a float so you don't get integer division.

```
select generate_series(1.0,99)/100;
```

and

```
select generate_series(1,99)/100.0;
```

also work but for some reason display with lots of trailing zeros.

Comment: In this instance I would use `* 0.01` instead of either `/ 100` or `/ 100.0`.

Comment: Interesting the difference between `SELECT FROM GENERATE_SERIES(...` and `SELECT GENERATE_SERIES (...` ~ 2 x! Might be of interest if you're generating millions of values...